# What I supposed to do with a "possibly" correct answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have a couple of accounts in different SE communities. I'm used to SO, where the concept is clear: you ask the question, and you get the answers with a "raw" knowledge, that you can apply immediately - if you can't get the raw-knowledge answer, then it's a probably bad question, that should be closed. The SO community rules support such scheme.

On other communities I have a problem with accepting answer, e.g. questions in Physics or Biology (see my accounts). I have a meaningful question - and I have answers. But I don't really know if those are correct. And even if they are correct, I can't get some "raw" knowledge from them - because I'm a newbie in this field.

What should I do: wait for better answers, improve questions, or just accept most voted - with a hope, it's a correct answer?

*P.S. I have revised my attitude about "silly" questions on SO, since the people may think the same way as I do: "Ummh, my question is about programming [biology, physics], but I'm a newbie. Where should I ask my question? - Let it be the SO [Biology, Physics] then :)"*

Answer (score 0):

You can never truly know the value of a solution untill in hindsight.  The main problem is that even a testable solution may be wrong. There may be many sources of taint or maybe it happens to work in a very limitted subset. The worst answer thus may be one that appears to work in a superficial inspection.

What im trying to say is even the most definitive SO answers have a huge "possible" attached to them. Your just better at interpretting them, some of the time.

Quite many subjects are not easily testable, in code less often but even there you have hard to test problems. In the sciences the convolution has gone quite far and the testability of certain things may in fact be currently practically impossible.

While many things may be tested it may also be time consuming to set up the test in the physical realm. Therefore you should fact check the sources of your answers first.

Just accept and upvote based on what you feel is helpfull. It may be a guess but its not the end of the world.